# Spring beans not getting @autowired in Jersey ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey authorization filter intended to get executed before an API call. But spring beans are not getting initialised, thus throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
@Provider
@Autherization
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityDAO<SessionDO> sessionDAO;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String requestSessionId = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("SESSION_ID");
        String username = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("USERNAME");
        Optional<SessionDO> session = sessionDAO.get(requestSessionId);
        if (session.isEmpty() || session.get().getExpiryTimestamp() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            throw new SessionExpiredException("User not logged in or session has expired");
        }
        if (!username.equals(session.get().getStudentDO().getUid())) {
            throw new InvalidUsernameException("Username is didn't match for given session id");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Bean is annotated with `@Component` as following

```
@Component
public class SessionDAOImpl extends EntityDAO<SessionDO> {

    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Override
    public Optional<SessionDO> get(String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(dynamoDBMapper.load(SessionDO.class, id));
    }
}
```

Why are beans not loaded into filter?

Comment: Please also show how you instantiate AuthorizationFilter

Comment: Is it a problem with just this filter or is the Spring to Jersey injection not working at all?

Comment: Yes it is, I am injecting it like this 
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kuldeepiitg/EbGjkG/springapplication
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kuldeepiitg/qnz6jB/authenticationservice

Comment: @Nobody filters are automatically scanned by Jersey, I need not/have not to initialise explicitly.

Comment: In order to autowire, you need to have the class in which you want to get bean autowired, to be within spring context. To be completely honest, never worked with jersey, but my bet is on the fact that you do need to declare filter as @Component / hook desired dao in a different manner

Comment: What you have linked to, this is not the correct way to integrate Spring with Jersey. What I see you doing is manually retrieving beans from the ApplicationContext yourself. You are not using injection. If you want to see how to integrate Spring injection into a Jersey project, have a look at [this example project](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I have to do the manual work only at first level i.e. service layer, subsequent layers are automatically injected by @ Autowire and @ Component facility. Nevertheless, I will look into the example you provide. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do _any_ manual work. Take a look at the project I linked to. Pay attention to the dependencies and the Config classes.